# problem in load() function

Tags: jquery

I'm facing a problem with `load()` function of jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
$("#addButton").click(function(){
    var textbox1 = $("#textbox1").val();
    alert(textbox1);
    $("#stage").load('/poll_view3.php', {"textbox1":textbox1} );
});
```

Where `addButton` is the id of a button and `textbox1` is the id of a text box.
I am working on CodeIgniter so when I call a view file containing this jQuery script it shows the button and text box too but when I click the button my another view `poll_view3` should be loaded inside a div tags with id "stage" as mentioned above but `poll_view3` is not loaded.

Please help me out solving this, thanks.

Comment: is the alert dialog displayed? if not, your click event is not firing.

Comment: What happens when you have `$("#stage").load('/poll_view3.php?textbox1=' + textbox1);` instead?

Comment: Take a look at the console, too. There may be an error in the request itself.

Comment: Are you having this issue on Google Chrome and from 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#stage").load('/poll_view3.php', {"textbox1":textbox1} );
```

i thought in this line you entered wrong URL make it write here

```
 $("#stage").load('../poll_view3.php', {"textbox1":textbox1} );
```

and if doesn't works then you can use `jQuery.ajax()` function for this

Comment: url "../poll_view3.php" is not working :s i have also tried something like i first made a test.php file in wamp/www folder and then instead of "../poll_view3" i put "test.php" but no use :( please guide me further

Comment: @mehwish have you tried what I suggested in the comment on your question?